# How to run Perl script in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a Perl script which is running fine on a Linux server, I am trying to execute the same from Jenkins using "execute shell" option.

Below is the output:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PTAF
[PTAF] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1860917719852476959.sh
+ perl /home/testtool/voice/code/SG_V1.0/Voice-data.pl
Can't open perl script "/home/testtool/voice/code/SG_V1.0/Voice-data.pl": Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any solution?

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `namei -lx /home/testtool/voice/code/SG_V1.0/Voice-data.pl` on the Jenkins server, please.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins can access/execute this file ? Please check permissions to this file else set permissions

```
chmod 755 /home/testtool/voice/code/SG_V1.0/Voice-data.pl
```

Comment: Already done the same. But same error.

Comment: can you execute that script normally via perl  ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have permissions all the way, i.e. all directories up until SG_V1.0 need at least +x for 'others'

```
chmod o+x /home
chmod o+x /home/testtool/
```

etc

Comment: what do mean by etc? Do you rather mean to set permissions recusrive using `sudo chmod o+x -R /home` ?

Comment: Correct, 'etc' mean to set permission for all included directories. Your suggestion is indeed an improved solution.